# Unable to generate Swagger UI for Spring Boot + Spring Integration using Spring REST Docs & springfox 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, swagger-ui, springfox

I am trying to setup Swagger for a Spring Boot + Spring Integration Project (involving an inbound-gateway) using Spring REST Docs style and springfox 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

On following the instructions from https://github.com/springfox/springfox/tree/master/springfox-spring-integration-webmvc, I was able to generate the following snippets under
**target/generated-snippets/{my-end-point-id}**:

- curl-request.springfox
- http-request.springfox
- http-response.springfox
- httpie-request.springfox
- request-body.springfox
- response-body.springfox

However, after this point, I am unable to create/generate the Swagger UI html in the packaged .war.
Is there any extra configuration/setup that is required for this?

As recommended, Springfox version: 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Other version details:
Spring Boot: 2.1.2.RELEASE
Spring Integration: 5.1.2.RELEASE
Java: 8
Apache Tomcat: 9.0.14
Apache Maven: 3.6.0

Please note that I wasn't clear whether to include a separate Swagger Configuration class with the @EnableSwagger2 annotation so I omitted this in my project setup.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with the help of examples from
https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/springfox-integration-webmvc.

Comment: I try this way but this isn't a real documentation like open-api .json.. starting from a file like the openapi docs json you can generate an entire client (in both java spring and Angular) simple putting inisde a tool like a swagger.io or using a maven plugin.