# How to create docs for spring-integration endpoint

Tags: swagger, spring-integration, openapi, spring-integration-http

I'm using a `SpringBoot 2.2.6` WebApplication with `Maven 3`. I'm also using `spring-integration-http` for my endpoint, that's mean that my endpoint are similar to follow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow test(CommonTransformer<TestDTO, String, TestMapper> testTransformer, Jackson2JsonObjectMapper obj) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo/{name}")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
            .payloadExpression("#pathVariables.name")
            .replyChannel(Constants.REPLY)
            .requestPayloadType(String.class))
            .transform(testTransformer)
            .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer(obj))
            .channel(Constants.HTTP_REQUEST)
            .get();
}
```

Now I would like to create a OpenApi docs for my endpoint and, if it's possible, a swagger GUI interface to test it.

I have read several official/unofficial docs and I find interesting docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681228/unable-to-generate-swagger-ui-for-spring-boot-spring-integration-using-spring) another much interesting example [here](https://github.com/escalon/springfox-demos/blob/feature/spring-integration-support/springfox-integration-webmvc/src/test/java/com/escalon/springfox/springintegration/SpringIntegrationWebMvcApplicationTest.java).

My preoccupation is that many of this articles are dated before 2020 (for example one of these use deprecated annotation likes `@EnableSwagger2Mvc`) but I can't managed to find out something more updated.

Is anyone aware of a more up-to-date procedure?

-------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------

First of all Thanks @ArtemBilan for yor response.

Yes I read that article and I'm not new to documenting my `REST API`. With `springdoc-openapi-ui` I'm able to create a `.json` file that, if putted in some editor like `http://swagger.io` or if used with a specific maven plugin can create a client (in both `spring java` and `Angular` language) ready for use.

I have tried the springfox way (above) to documenting my `spring-integration-http` but it sucks! It generate some useless files to reproduce the call via CURL..

Is not what I'm looking for. I must (the STO asks) documenting my endpoint like the `.yaml` you can find for the example [Swagger Pet Store](https://editor.swagger.io/?_ga=2.18295545.1328353296.1655916903-776694596.1649083461).

And it seems there's no way with this `spring-integration-http` to do so..

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried this one: https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs? I'm not familiar with the project, but looks like it should lead to an up-to-date API.

Comment: had any luck? I need to document Spring Integration HTTP endpoints as well